Firebase Multi-Factor Authentication Suddenly Failing with 500 Internal Server Error in Flutter App
I've been using Firebase Authentication with Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) in my Flutter app (web) without issues for the past 6 months. Recently, I started encountering a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to initiate MFA. No code changes were made to the authentication logic. It was working before, some days ago I startet getting this 500 error on the mfa:start endpoint.
Packages:
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^4.14.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1

Error Message:
{error: {code: 500, message: "Internal error encountered.", status: "INTERNAL"}}

Checked the Endpoint calls, this throws 500:
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/mfaSignIn:start?key=MY_API_KEY
In the body request it also contains all the neccessary info:
{
    "mfaPendingCredential": "AMzJoSk ... MFA PENDING CREDENTIAL",
    "mfaEnrollmentId": "db86e89e-b3c6-47cb ... ENROLLMENT ID ",
    "phoneSignInInfo": {
        "recaptchaToken": "03AFcWe... RECAPTCHA"
    }
}

The signInWithEmailAndPassword and recaptcha endpoint runs to 200, and returns back the mfa-id and all the other info related and needed.
What I've Tried:

Retrying the request: Multiple times with no success.
Checking Firebase Status: No reported outages or issues.
Reviewing API Documentation: No updates or deprecations found related to my issue.
Updating Dependencies: Cant really update it easily, because this is an old project, and have dependency conflict with the latest Flutter, but as I said, this project has been running since 6 month without issues.

Additional Info:
I found a note about cross-origin redirect sign-in on Google Chrome M115+ stopping on June 24, 2024. However, I don't think this is related as my issue is with the signInWithEmailAndPassword and it should not affects phone auth MFA process itself?!
Questions:

What could be causing this sudden 500 Internal Server Error?
Has there been any recent changes to Firebase Auth that could affect MFA?
How can I debug or resolve this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

